# Python `Ошибка invalid command name ".!canvas"`

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to teach children to program in Python. I don't know him myself. We started simple, the ball bounces on the screen. We caught a mistake, Google does not help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KrehtaFamily\Desktop\Programms\kirr\first.py", line 54, in <module>
    MoveBall()
  File "C:\Users\KrehtaFamily\Desktop\Programms\kirr\first.py", line 39, in MoveBall
    PaintBall(1,x_start,y_start)
  File "C:\Users\KrehtaFamily\Desktop\Programms\kirr\first.py", line 23, in PaintBall
    holst.create_oval(x_coord, y_coord, x_coord+30, y_coord+30, fill=fill_color, outline=out_color)#Рисуем мяч на холсте
  File "C:\Users\KrehtaFamily\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2798, in create_oval
    return self._create('oval', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\KrehtaFamily\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2776, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

We need an endless window redrawing loop. An endless loop has been created. Rendering by calling Tk.update (). As a result, an error pops up if you click on the cross to close the window. It is clear that the problem is incorrect termination. I tried the options. Useless. How to complete correctly.
It would be possible to score, the program works, but the principles require you to understand and fix the bug :)
script below

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def on_closing():
    global window
    window.destroy()  # Закрыть окно

def PaintBall(paint_command, x_coord, y_coord):
    '''
    Функция PaintBell - Рисование мяча на экране
    paint_command - 1- Нарисовать мяч, красным. 2 - Нарисовать мяч черным
    x_coord - Координата X
    y_coord - Координата Y
    '''
    global holst
    global window
    if paint_command == 1:
        fill_color = 'red'
        out_color = 'white'
    else:
        fill_color = 'black'
        out_color = 'black'
    holst.create_oval(x_coord, y_coord, x_coord+30, y_coord+30, fill=fill_color, outline=out_color)#Рисуем мяч на холсте
    time.sleep(0.1)
    window.update()
    

def MoveBall():
    global x_start
    global y_start
    global step
    PaintBall(2,x_start,y_start)
    x_start=x_start+step
    if (x_start+step) > 170:
        step = -10
    elif (x_start+step) < 1:
        step = 10
    x_start=x_start+step
    PaintBall(1,x_start,y_start)

x_start=100
y_start=100
step=10
window = Tk() #Создаем окно
window.title("Сбежавший мячик!!!") #Выводим название программы в окне
window.geometry("200x200+100+100") #задаем размер окна
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
holst = Canvas(window, width=200, height=200, bg='black') #Задаем окно, размер, и цвет холста
holst.pack() #Рисуем холст в окне
PaintBall(1,x_start,y_start)

a = 1
while a < 5:
    MoveBall()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: This error means you're trying to call a method on a widget that has been destroyed, or exists in a different window.

Comment: Good day. I am trying to teach children to program in Python. Python is unfamiliar to me. We started out simple. The ball bounces across the screen. An execution error will fly out, it does not help to google.

Comment: Found a solution. Endless loop replaced holst.after_idle(MoveBall) + holst.after(2000,MoveBall)

Comment: @АленаКрехта: If you found an answer to your question, please post it as an answer. It is okay to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of problems with your code.

Your function `PaintBall` was creating a new `oval` object every time it was called.

You were using `time.sleep` that interferes with `tkinter` events.

The code now works with smooth animation due to the use of `after` set to 50 milliseconds and a reduction of the ball increment value from 10 to 5.

```py
from tkinter import *

def on_closing():
    global window
    window.destroy()  # Закрыть окно

def PaintBall(paint_command, x_coord, y_coord):
    '''
    Функция PaintBell - Рисование мяча на экране
    paint_command - 1- Нарисовать мяч, красным. 2 - Нарисовать мяч черным
    x_coord - Координата X
    y_coord - Координата Y
    '''
    global holst, window, ball
    if paint_command == 1:
        fill_color = 'red'
        out_color = 'white'
    else:
        fill_color = 'black'
        out_color = 'black'
    holst.coords(ball, x_coord, y_coord, x_coord+30, y_coord+30)
    holst.itemconfig(ball, fill = fill_color, outline = out_color)

def MoveBall(paint_command, x_start, y_start):
    global step
    PaintBall(paint_command, x_start, y_start)
    x_start=x_start+step
    if (x_start+step) > 170:
        step = -5
    elif (x_start+step) < 0:
        step = 5
    x_start=x_start+step
    # animation set to 50 milliseconds
    holst.after( 50, MoveBall, 1, x_start, y_start)

x_start=100
y_start=100
step=10
window = Tk() #Создаем окно
window.title("Сбежавший мячик!!!") #Выводим название программы в окне
window.geometry("200x200+100+100") #задаем размер окна
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
holst = Canvas(window, width=200, height=200, bg='black') #Задаем окно, размер, и цвет холста
holst.pack() #Рисуем холст в окне
# create ball ONCE
ball = holst.create_oval( 0, 0, 30, 30, fill = 'red', outline = 'white') #Рисуем мяч на холсте
# start the ball 'rolling'
holst.after( 100, MoveBall, 1, x_start, y_start)

window.mainloop()
```